# Is it safe to remove OSB board and wood support from cold room

Tags: insulation, basement, porch

I have a cold room under the front porch. It has OSB boards on the ceiling that are supported by a number of 2x4s. I want to seal the hole to outside and covered the ceiling and walls with 2inch XPS boards. My understanding is that the OSB boards and 2x4s are only used when building the porch and not needed after. The room is about 8x12.

Comment: It's not clear at all what the OSB you're describing was intended to do. Photos seem to be a requirement here.

Comment: Is the front porch above the cold room poured concrete?